# Elegant way to init or inject string into a static field beforeClass (JUNIT) from spring configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

The annotation **@Value("${my.field}")** work well if you want to inject data into a **non** static field.

In my case, I'm building test for my spring boot application. I'm using Junit. I have some task to do **@BeforeClass** and I need some properties from spring application configuration. I'm looking for a elegant way to get my properties.

Comment: you can autowire Environment in test class and get the properties from env.getproperty("propertyname")

Comment: **@Autowired Environment environment ** is not static. In the @beforeClass (static method), I can't use "environment".

Comment: Could you please share what you are trying with. if you want certain properties to be loaded in your test class you can ```@Autowired ```Environment environment and make use of ```@PostConstruct``` method to initialize the properties required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the properties file in the static setup method on your own and select the values needed in your tests. For some, it might be less convenient than injection with @Value, but it will do the trick.

```
public class SomeTestClass {

    private static String myProperty;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/application.properties"));
        myProperty = prop.getProperty("your.property.key");
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldLoadProperty() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("expectedValue", myProperty);
    }

}
```